# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "none" does not exist - Update Statement

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I keep encountering the error "psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "none" does not exist".

I have read the [psycopg2 documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) and looked at other posts on this error, however, many are specific to an **insert query** rather than an **update query**.

My code is as follows:-

```
def send_to_sql(identity,list1,list2,list3):
    userid = 30
    Fixture_No = None
    Home_Side_Score = None
    Away_Side_Score = None
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='Euro2016' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='##passwordhere##'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""UPDATE "Predictions" SET userid = %r, "Fixture_No" = %r, "Home_Side_Score" = %r, "Away_Side_Score" = %r WHERE "Predictions"."userid" = %r AND "Predictions"."Fixture_No" = %r """ % (userid, Fixture_No, Home_Side_Score, Away_Side_Score, userid, Fixture_No))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

This code works fine if scores and fixture number I am trying to pass are numbers but when a None entry is made, the code falls on its face. Somebody save me...

Comment: offtopic hint: use prepared statements http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2012/10/01/prepared-statements-psycopg/ there are much safer it the way they create sql with foreign variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%s` not `%r`. To check what is being sent to the server use `cursor. mogrify`:

```py
update = """
    UPDATE "Predictions"
    SET 
        userid = %s, 
        "Fixture_No" = %s, 
        "Home_Side_Score" = %s, 
        "Away_Side_Score" = %s
    WHERE 
        "Predictions"."userid" = %s AND 
        "Predictions"."Fixture_No" = %s
"""
data = (userid, Fixture_No, Home_Side_Score, Away_Side_Score, userid, Fixture_No)
print cur.mogrify(update, data)
cur.execute(update, data)
```

Still better, use a dictionary to pass the data:

```
update = """
    UPDATE "Predictions"
    SET
        userid = %(userid)s, 
        "Fixture_No" = %(Fixture_no)s,
        "Home_Side_Score" = %(Home_Side_Score)s,
        "Away_Side_Score" = %(Away_Side_Score)s
    WHERE
        "Predictions"."userid" = %(userid)s AND
        "Predictions"."Fixture_No" = %(Fixture_No)s
"""
data = dict (
    userid = userid,
    Fixture_No = Fixture_No,
    Home_Side_Score = Home_Side_Score,
    Away_Side_Score = Away_Side_Score
)
```

Comment: Fantastic help, this did the trick. Just used 'update' where you had written 'query' and it did the job. Thanks!

Comment: Out of interest, why does this none type error occur? I have run some separate code elsewhere using %s and I still get the same error. I could do with understanding in general why this type of error occurs.

Comment: @LemusThelroy Are the target columns nullable?

Comment: They are not. It confuses me that the value None, determines what column it is looking for.

Comment: @LemusThelroy Psycopg adapts a Python `None`  to a SQL `null`. You are trying to insert a null into a not nullable column.

Comment: @Clodaldo Neto My table allows null entries...shall I post a separate question?

CREATE TABLE "Predictions"
(
  userid smallint,
  "Fixture_No" smallint,
  "Home_Side_Score" smallint,
  "Away_Side_Score" smallint,
  "Prediction_ID" bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Predictions_Prediction_ID_seq"'::regclass),
  "Joker_Played" boolean,
  "Result" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 4,
  CONSTRAINT "Predictions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (),
  CONSTRAINT "Result_Type" FOREIGN KEY ()
      REFERENCES "ResultTypes" () MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

Comment: @LemusThelroy Yes create a new question with the exact text of the error message

Comment: Can you link here the question you created @LemusThelroy?